# Running Ruby Script/Program and interacting in command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have seen it before but I cannot remember where. I have a Ruby program that I'd like to execute and interact with in command line and call the functions. Similar to irb but within that program. For example:

```
class Message
  @@messages_sent = 0
  def initialize (from, to)
    @from = from
    @to = to
    @@messages_sent +=1
  end   
end
class Email < Message
  def initialize (from,to)
   super
  end
end
```

and I want to run the script and call functions such as

```
my_message = Message.new('NYC','TDOT')
```

How? I did the ruby myprogram.rb and just runs it and closes it, I actually want to enter into the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first require IRB and then type `IRB.start` where you want to start it:

```
require 'irb'

IRB.start
```